# And, == operators in the same python if statement

Tags: python-3.x

Given a list of integers:

```
old_list = [1,1,2,-2,5,2,4,4,-1,-2,5]
```

I run the following code to get all the integers grouped in a list of lists:

```
old_list.sort()
    new_list = []
    for i in old_list:
        if new_list == []:
            new_list.append([i])
        elif new_list[-1][0] == i:
            new_list[-1].append(i)
        else:
            new_list.append([i])
    print(new_list)
```

Returning my desired output:

```
[[-2, -2], [-1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 4], [5, 5]]
```

On the one hand I found I could condense the if elif statement using `and`, while retrieving the same output:

```
old_list.sort()
    new_list = []
    for i in old_list:
        if new_list and new_list[-1][0] == i:
            new_list[-1].append(i)
        else:
            new_list.append([i])
    print(new_list)
```

On the other hand if I try to remove the `new_list and` from the if statement the following error arises:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why isn't the `if new_list and new_list[-1][0] == i:` statement firing the same index error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because first you check that `new_list` is not empty, so at least it has a last element. When you remove this check, since your `new_list` is initially empty, `new_list[-1]` is out of range.

Comment: @pyn00b that's called short-circuiting. If `new_list` is empty, the other part of the `and` will not even be checked and the whole condition is false. On the other hand, if it is true, you know that there is at least one element...